# REST based web chat in java and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, jakarta-ee, acceptverbs

I want to create a REST based chat application in Java using Eclipse, but I have no idea how to start. How do I take care of resources, verbs, and HEATOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://jersey.java.net/), or this [link](http://restlet.org), or this [link](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/). I would personally recommend Jersey. restelt is very powerful, but might be quite complicated. RESTeasy has more features than jersey, but it can also be a pain to configure outside JBoss, and their community is not as 'active'. I would recommend Jersey, their startup tutorial is very easy to follow.

You can also look at this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521134.do), and this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158057.do). Sorry, I can't provide any hard answers as I have no knowledge, your level of expertise on the subject. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hay greenkode I wanna use Atmosphere. Can u please help me with that !